# OpenSSH not working for Ubuntu Server I set up

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I just set up a ubuntu server using the [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/comment-page-1/#comments) tutorial.  I can connect with SSH fine but when I try to move things onto the server, I am getting this error:

```
Permission denied (SSH_FX_PERMISSION_DENIED: The user does not have sufficient permissions to perform the operation.).
```

I know I did things like

```
sudo usermod -g www-data [MY USERNAME]
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

So I have no idea why it isn't working.  Can anyone offer suggestions?

Comment: What is the command line that you are running when you do the movement of data?

Comment: I am using cyberduck.  although I've also tried scp on the command line and got `scp: /var/www//index.html: Permission denied`

Comment: What command line did you use when you tried scp?

Answer (score 2):

To copy files:

```
scp myfiles.zip myusername@mywebserver.com:
```

Now log in normally and copy the files to /var/www

```
ssh -l myusername mywebserver.com
unzip myfiles.zip
sudo cp myfiles/* /var/www
```

You need `sudo` in order to put the files in the directory that is owned by www-data. If you want to avoid sudo, then you will need to set up www-data as a real login user with a password, and their home directory set to /var/www. Then you can move individual files with scp and not have to log in with ssh.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www
```

change www-data to whatever user you are logged in as. In my case it was ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a straightforward file permissions error. The user with which you are connecting with cyberduck doesn't have permissions to do the file operation.

It is a good idea to try doing a similar operation over SCP at the commandline to double-check cyberduck isn't playing tricks on you. Here you'll see a quick 'permission denied' error.

Make sure you're connecting as www-data if that's the user who owns the file... although it's possibly a bit unusual to connect as this user. Alternatives? Connect as 'root'. Try to write files to some different destination directory e.g. your user home directory or /tmp  This maybe an adequate workaround, if you can then move files after transferring them, but do this test anyway as a sanity check.

Personally I hit this error with one particular file because I'd accidentally caused root to become the owner of the file itself (not the directory it was in), but your -R  commands should take care of that.

Another gotcha I remember hitting a while back: Do you have "SELinux" enabled?

Answer (score 0):

- sudo groupadd vivek
- sudo useradd -g vivek -G www-data vivek
- sudo passwd vivek
- sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
- sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www

In your usermod ***Capital G is important*** -G
because i did what you did and it fixed my ftp error
I think you setup the group relationship wrong somehow